# Combine columns along the same index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to use `pandas` to wrangle a ~500mb tab-separated data file in the following format:

```
+-------+---------+-------+---------+-------+---------+
| Time1 | Sensor1 | Time2 | Sensor2 | Time3 | Sensor3 |
+-------+---------+-------+---------+-------+---------+
|     0 | x       |     0 | y       | 0     | z       |
|     1 | x       |     2 | y       | 0.5   | z       |
|     2 | x       |     4 | y       | 1     | z       |
|     3 | x       |       |         | 1.5   | z       |
|     4 | x       |       |         | 2     | z       |
|     5 | x       |       |         | 2.5   | z       |
|       |         |       |         | 3     | z       |
|       |         |       |         | 3.5   | z       |
|       |         |       |         | 4     | z       |
|       |         |       |         | 4.5   | z       |
|       |         |       |         | 5     | z       |
+-------+---------+-------+---------+-------+---------+
```

I would like to get all the sensor values along one time axis, such as below:

```
+------+---------+---------+---------+
| Time | Sensor1 | Sensor1 | Sensor3 |
+------+---------+---------+---------+
| 0    | x       | y       | z       |
| 0.5  | NaN     | NaN     | z       |
| 1    | x       | NaN     | z       |
| 1.5  | NaN     | NaN     | z       |
| 2    | x       | y       | z       |
| 2.5  | NaN     | NaN     | z       |
| 3    | x       | NaN     | z       |
| 3.5  | NaN     | NaN     | z       |
| 4    | x       | y       | z       |
| 4.5  | NaN     | NaN     | z       |
| 5    | x       | NaN     | z       |
+------+---------+---------+---------+
```

I've started with the following code. The looping part works OK (though it takes an incredibly long time). However, the `concat` part results in a lot of duplicate time indexes and doesn't combine multiple sensor values into one row.

```
import pandas as pd
dfList = []
numberOfChannels = 3
for x in range(0,numberOfChannels):
    columns = [numberOfChannels]
    frame = pd.read_table('testinput.csv', 
                          usecols = [x*2, x*2+1],
                          index_col = 0)
    frame.index.name = 'time'
    frame.index = pd.to_timedelta(frame.index, unit = 'ms')

    dfList.append(frame)
df = pd.concat(dfList)
```

Is there a better way of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a list of series and then use `pandas.concat` to combine them into a single dataframe.

The solution is functionally identical to @DyZ, but laid out differently.

```
series_list = [df.set_index('Time'+str(i))['Sensor'+str(i)].dropna() \
               for i in range(1, int(len(df.columns)/2) + 1)]

res = pd.concat(series_list, axis=1)\
        .rename_axis('Time').reset_index()
```

**Setup**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Time1': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
                   'Sensor1': ['x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
                   'Time2': [0, 2, 4, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
                   'Sensor2': ['y', 'y', 'y', np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
                   'Time3': [0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 4, 4.5, 5],
                   'Sensor3': ['z', 'z', 'z', 'z', 'z', 'z', 'z', 'z', 'z', 'z', 'z']})
```

**Result**

```
print(res)

    Time Sensor1 Sensor2 Sensor3
0    0.0       x       y       z
1    0.5     NaN     NaN       z
2    1.0       x     NaN       z
3    1.5     NaN     NaN       z
4    2.0       x       y       z
5    2.5     NaN     NaN       z
6    3.0       x     NaN       z
7    3.5     NaN     NaN       z
8    4.0       x       y       z
9    4.5     NaN     NaN       z
10   5.0       x     NaN       z
```

Comment: +1 For explaining how your solution works and for breaking it up into two readable steps. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

The following code worked for me:

```
df = pd.read_table('testinput.csv')

pd.concat([df[['Time{}'.format(i), 'Sensor{}'.format(i)]]\
           .set_index('Time{}'.format(i)) \
           for i in range(1, numberOfChannels + 1)], axis=1)\
          .dropna(how='all')
#     Sensor1  Sensor2
#0.0      1.0      1.0
#1.0      2.0      NaN
#2.0      1.0      2.0
#3.0      2.0      NaN
#4.0      1.0      1.0
#5.0      2.0      NaN
#6.0      1.0      NaN
```